# How to insert JPanel beside a grid?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, grid-layout

I just built this grid using (Java Swing library), and this is the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestGrid02 extends JPanel {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   protected static final Color SELECTION_COLOR = Color.red;
   private JPanel selectedPanel = null;
   private Color originalColor = new Color(238,238,238) ;
   private static final Dimension PREF_SIZE = new Dimension(50, 50);
   public JPanel panel;
   public JPanel panel_1;
   public JFrame frame;



   public TestGrid02() {

    createMap(10,10);

   }


   public void createMap(int maxX,int maxY) {    

       String [ ][ ] map = new String [maxX][maxY];

      for (int i = 0; i < maxX; i++) {

          for (int j = 0; j < maxY ; j++) {
              map [i][j] = "["+ i + ","+  j +"]";


          JPanel panel = new JPanel();
              add(panel);
              panel.setPreferredSize(PREF_SIZE);
              String name = String.format("[%d, %d]",  i, j);
              setLayout(new GridLayout(maxX,maxY, 1, 1));
              setBackground(Color.GRAY);
              panel.setName(name);

              System.out.println( map [i][j]); 
          }
      }

      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
          @Override
          public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
             JPanel panel = (JPanel) getComponentAt(e.getPoint());

             if (panel == null || panel == TestGrid02.this) {
                return;
             }

             if (selectedPanel != null) {
                selectedPanel.setBackground(originalColor);
                selectedPanel.removeAll();
                selectedPanel.revalidate();
                selectedPanel.repaint();
             }

             selectedPanel = panel;
             selectedPanel.setBackground(SELECTION_COLOR);
             selectedPanel.add(new JLabel(selectedPanel.getName()));
             selectedPanel.revalidate();
             selectedPanel.repaint();
          }
       });

  }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Astar");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new TestGrid02());
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);     
      frame.pack();


   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

But what I want is to add another `JPanel` to the "east" of the grid that contains for example 2 text areas and 1 button like this image -- **[1]**:

[image]

I already tried to add another panel but it appears on the top of the grid. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: *"how can solve this problem?"* Combine layouts.  Use a `GridLayout` for the buttons, then add that panel to a (new 2nd panel) with another layout.  Add your other panel to the 2nd panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by combining layouts. Use a `GridLayout` for the buttons, then add that panel to a (new 2nd panel) with another layout. Add your other panel to the 2nd panel.  This example sets a different color to each of the main panels to show how they work together.

[image]

Note that for that screenshot, I made the grid of panels half size.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TestGrid02  {

    private static final Dimension PREF_SIZE = new Dimension(50, 50);
    private JPanel ui;
    private JPanel gameGrid;

    public TestGrid02() {
        initUI();
    }

    private final void initUI() {
        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        ui.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        createMap(10, 10);
        ui.add(gameGrid);

        JPanel controlsConstrain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.add(controlsConstrain, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        controlsConstrain.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        JPanel controls = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 25));
        controlsConstrain.add(controls, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        controls.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        controls.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(40, 20, 20, 20));
        controls.add(new JTextField(10));
        controls.add(new JTextField(10));
        controls.add(new JButton("OK"));
    }

    public void createMap(int maxX, int maxY) {
        gameGrid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(maxX, maxY, 1, 1));
        gameGrid.setBackground(Color.RED);

        for (int i = 0; i < maxX; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < maxY; j++) {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setPreferredSize(PREF_SIZE);
                String name = String.format("[%d, %d]", i, j);
                panel.setName(name);
                gameGrid.add(panel);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Astar");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TestGrid02().getUi());
        // this was being called at the wrong time, but ..
        // frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // ..better to..
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);  // should be last.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

    public JPanel getUi() {
        return ui;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `BorderLayout`. Something like this (I have not tested it but you can start here and continue by yourself):

```
public TestGrid02() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    createMap(centerPanel, 10,10);
    add(otherPanel, BorderLayout.EAST); // otherPanel contains your buttons, text fields, etc.
}
```

And in the `createMap` method change:

```
add(panel);
```

by:

```
centerPanel.add(panel);
```

Comment: I followed your solution, but the centerPanel went down, while the other panel moved up

Comment: Maybe this `setLayout(new GridLayout(maxX,maxY, 1, 1));` should be `panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(maxX,maxY, 1, 1));`